# Can't push to git repo bc terminal not recognizing correct username and pass?

Tags: git, github, push

I'm following this [tutorial](https://github.com/Filet-Mignogna/silver-happiness) and got stuck when trying to push material to my git repo:

[image]

Comment: Either your username and/or password is wrong, or you have been blocked from the repository.

Comment: Do you have 2FA turned on in Github? If so, you'll need to use an access token instead of your password.

Comment: oh whoops, linked wrong doc:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This could be a number of things depending on your repo configuration, but most commonly:

1. your credentials are incorrect (username/password typos)
2. you do not have "push" rights to that repo.
3. you need to use an access token instead of password.

Comment: I should have push rights as I just made it. Unless I'm failing super hard I know my username and password. Why might I need to use an access token and how could I do that?

Comment: it's something you would have setup when you created your GitHub repo. if it doesn't sound familiar then I wouldn't worry about it. What tutorial are you following? the link you provided takes me to: https://github.com/Filet-Mignogna/silver-happiness

Comment: oh whoops, linked wrong doc. Here it is
http://readwrite.com/2014/07/18/command-line-tutorial-intro

Comment: I think I fixed it. I tried to change my password to try again but apparently my old password wasn't correct...maybe I mis-typed it when I made the account, since you only have to type it once there. Anyway, I'm making a new username and password and everything else should be okay!

Comment: Awesome! Thanks for updating.. Since "technically" it was due to bad credentials which was my first suggestion, could you up vote and mark my answer as correct?

Answer (score 0):

+1 to the concerns on username/password. It may be easier to determine by configuring your [git credentials through keychain](https://help.github.com/articles/caching-your-github-password-in-git/).

Alternatively, use a SSH key for your authentication to GitHub: https://help.github.com/articles/generating-ssh-keys/

Git and GitHub take time to learn - watch some of the lessons taught [on Commitmas](https://github.com/commitmas/30-days-of-commitmas-2015#vbrownbag-commitmas-schedule) to quickly pick up on the nuances.